# IONIC / REACT Line 9:5: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

When i try to make hook to get userdata from firebase. Like this

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { firestore } from '../../'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
export function useUserDetails() {
  const db = firestore;
  const userid = getAuth().currentUser?.uid
  const [userDetails, setuserDetails] = useState<unknown>([])
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
     const doc = await db.collection("Users").doc(userid).get();
      setuserDetails(({...doc.data(), id: doc.id}))
  })}, [])
  return [userDetails]
}
```

react return me a error :  Line 9:5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke the anonymous function in your useEffect. It looks like you have an extra set of parens in your setuserDetails call. Also, are `doc.data()` and `doc.id` both correct?

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const doc = await db.collection("Users").doc(userid).get();
    // removed parens
    setuserDetails({...doc.data(), id: doc.id}));
  // added parens
  })();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: This is correct way to useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async function() {
      const doc = await db.collection("Users").doc(userid).get();
      setuserDetails(({...doc.data(), id: doc.id}))
    })();
}, []);
```